# navbar list items changing size depending on list string length

Tags: html, css

I made a navbar that supposedly has list items that are evenly distributed along the navbar, although it seems that list items with longer string lengths have a bigger width than others. Is there a way to fix this?

```
<div id="menu-bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=#>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="ferrari.html">Ferrari</a></li>
        <li><a href="lamborghini.html">Lamborghini</a></li>
        <li><a href="bugatti.html">Bugatti</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#menu-bar {
background-color: #51F069;
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
border-top: 2px solid #8f8f8f;
border-bottom: 2px solid #8f8f8f;
display: table;
}

#menu-bar li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
font-family: Ferrari;
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
}

#menu-bar a {
display: block;
font-size: 25px;
line-height: 40px;
}

#menu-bar ul {
width: 100%;
display: table;
}
```

Comment: in a `#menu-bar li ` you defined `display:` twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a default behavior, they're set to `display:table-cell`. If you look at an HTML table, the cells with longer content will take more space in the table.

Simply set a `width` to your list-items :

```
#menu-bar li {
    list-style-type: none;       
    font-family: Ferrari;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%; /* 100% / 4 li's */
```

}

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sa7x258k/1/

Comment: check this snippet because you CAN'T have 2 `display` properties. the last one will override the first one.

Comment: I just noticed the first `display` now, fixed!